# How do I make the y-axis values bold in R?

Tags: r, fonts, boxplot

I have a box plot and want to make the values of the y-axis bold.
I know how to make the y-axis title bold.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `par`:

```
par(font.axis = 2) # 2 means 'bold'
boxplot(1:10)
```

An alternative way using `axis` (proposed by @joran):

```
boxplot(1:10, yaxt = "n") # suppress y axis
axis(side = 2, font = 2)  # 'side = 2' means y axis
```

[image]

You can reset to normal typeface using `par(font.axis = 1)`.

Comment: Suppressing the axis and then calling `axis` directly using `font` argument would be the other option.

Answer (score 3):

Using `lattice`

```
 library(lattice)
 bwplot(~1:10,scales=list(x=list(font=2,cex=5)))
```

[image]